# OpenCV 4.3.0 compute integral image on GPU>

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

So I found the function to compute the GPU integral image [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html).

The functions I need are `gpu::integral` and `gpu::sqrIntegral` (if there's a function that compute both the integral image and squared integral image at the same time, it would be best).

However, in OpenCV 4.3.0, I cannot find these functions at all. I can only find the CPU version [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gadeaf38d7701d7ad371278d663c50c77d) . Where have the GPU version been moved to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `cv::gpu::integral` in the namespace `cv::cuda`. There're many changed between OpenCV 2 and 4. I hope that you also refer to `UMat` which accelerates using OpenCL and easy to learn.

Comment: How exactly do I call the function? I can't find cv::gpu at all :\ Or cv:;cuda::gpu, ...

Comment: @DukeLe, Does your OpenCV 4 build with GPU support? It not, the namespace is not available and in visible.

Comment: I didn't think about that. Does the GPU version have an installer that I can download? Or do I have to build the source myself?

Comment: @DukeLe, OpenCV for Windows provides minimum features for compatibility. You need to build your own OpenCV using CMAKE and CUDA. You also need to download extra module since CUDA support is moved to extra module from OpenCV 4.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this